# trying to convert rails 2.3.4 app to rails 3 but views not appearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple rails 2.3.4 application I am trying to get running with rails 3.0.0-beta2. I have the server running and all my links and navigation showing, however for some reason the content of my views is not displaying.

When I navigate to Site/index the html in my index.html.erb in my site view is completely ignored. There are no errors in the server log.

My template is rendered properly (where all the links and navigation are being created) within application.html.erb however all of my actual view files are being ignored.

Has anyone experienced this?

I am using old style routing with map.connect, could this be the issue? Does anyone have a tutorial on how to convert old routes to new ones? I couldn't figure it out.

my current routes look like this:

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
map.root :controller => :site, :action => :index
```

edit: Solved my problem by using yield instead of @content_for_layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Engine Yard blog has a good [guide to the new router](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I upgraded to using the new routes however my stuff still isn't showing up. I don't get it ??? 

figured it out! turns out i had to change @content_for_layout to yield.

Comment: Crazy, that was driving me nuts for the last half an hour.  Thanks kgrad.